# Python - You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

Seems this is a commun issue when using Facebook APIs. I am trying to use the ads API using Python. When I am testing it using the Graph API Explorer, I have the version 9.0 and I am not getting any errors. I am trying to implement the API call using Python but when I am specifiying the version 9.0, I am getting this error log:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: Valid API versions are '2.8', '2.9', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12', '3.0', '3.1'
```

My code:

```
import facebook
token = "<token>"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version="9.0")
events = graph.request("?ids=<id>")
print(events)
```

But when I am using the version `3.1` or `< than 3.1`, I am getting another error:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v9.0.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems related to an older SDK (see the code on [github](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/3fa89fec6a20dd070ccf57968c6f89256f237f54/facebook/__init__.py#L44))

I suggest you to update to the official [Facebook SDK for Python](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk)